# Cannot match new id to id in SESSION variable

Tags: php, session

Using PHP, my objective is to prevent the addition of a duplicate ID into a SESSION cart. The ID is passed from a form. The error message works for the first item only. Other items already in the cart bypass the conditional statement and are added to the array, although the first item at any point gets caught by it. Various trial and error remedies have failed.

Any assistance is appreciated. Let me know if this challenge is not described clearly. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code:

```
// If user clicks add button
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'Add'){ 

// If cart has content, check if new content already in cart
if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id){
        if($_POST['id'] === $id){
            $errMsg = 'Item ' . $_POST['id'] . ' already in cart.';
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();                                              
        }else{
           // Add new content to cart
           $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id'];
           header('Location: .');
           exit();
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: Try using `in_array` instead of `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, it should work, also there was an xss vulnerability in this code so i fixed it too.

read owasp's guide for more info https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user clicks add button
if($_POST['action'] === 'Add'){
    if(in_array($_POST['id'], $_SESSION['cart'])){
        $errMsg = 'Item ' . htmlentities($_POST['id'],ENT_QUOTES) /* Cross Site Scripting */ . ' already in cart.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    // Add new content to cart
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id'];
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Abdallah Samman,  Thank you! Thank you for taking the time. It works perfectly! Thank you also for the extra security measure.  I will review the in_array function to understand its application here and moving forward. THIS SOLUTION MERITS THE GREEN CHECKMARK! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :), please don't forget to mark this answer as the correct answer so it won't appear in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using an `===` operator which also checks for type-equality,
   not knowing how your `$_POST` data comes in, this might be an issue.

   Try executing a `var_dump` on both `$_POST['id']` and
   `$_SESSION['cart']` before and post modification to determine what
   variable types you are dealing with and to see how the `cart` array
   changes.
2. Do you properly start a session using [`session_start`](https://php.net/session_start)? You might want to read [this quick introduction](https://php.net/session.examples.basic) on PHP sessions.

Comment: I do not believe changing the compare operator would solve OPs issues, neither checking sessions, since it gets to the IF statement already passed of session verification.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies. session_start() - started, yes. Fails with === and ==. var_dump on $_POST['id'] matches database. var_dump on $_SESSION['cart'] shows ID string that grows with each addition, e.g. add ID 181, then ID 33, then ID 33 again produces string: 181, then string 18133, then string 1813333, respectively.

Comment: Some additional information.  When I add three items to the cart and echo for content, here's what I get:

Comment: count($_SESSION['cart']) 3
$_SESSION['cart'][0]181
$_SESSION['cart'][1]33
$_SESSION['cart'][2]122

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution or have a question?